# How to get intermediate outputs in TF 2.3 Eager with learning_phase?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, tensorflow2.x

Example below works in 2.2; `K.function` is changed significantly in 2.3, [now building](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.3/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L3936) a `Model` in Eager execution, so we're passing `Model(inputs=[learning_phase,...])`.

I do have a workaround in mind, but it's hackish, and lot more complex than `K.function`; if none can show a simple approach, I'll post mine.

---

```py
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

ipt = Input((16,))
x   = Dense(16)(ipt)
out = Dense(16)(x)
model = Model(ipt, out)
model.compile('sgd', 'mse')

outs_fn = K.function([model.input, K.symbolic_learning_phase()],
                     [model.layers[1].output])  # error
x = np.random.randn(32, 16)
print(outs_fn([x, True]))
```

```
>>> ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`. 
Received: Tensor("keras_learning_phase:0", shape=(), dtype=bool) 
(missing previous layer metadata).
```

Comment: Does this work for your use case: `K.function([symbolic_inputs], [symbolic_outputs])([input_arrays], training=True)`?

Comment: I misunderstood the recent change. Actually, the `K.function` does not return a `Model` instance (although, it builds and run a `Model` instance). But for your use case in the question, why don't you do this instead: `partial_model = Model(model.inputs, model.layers[1].output)` and then use `partial_model([x], training=True)` to run it in training mode. If you have another special use case, please include it in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For fetching output of an intermediate layer in eager mode it's not necessary to build a `K.function` and use learning phase. Instead, we can build a model to achieve that:

```
partial_model = Model(model.inputs, model.layers[1].output)

x = np.random.rand(...)
output_train = partial_model([x], training=True)   # runs the model in training mode
output_test = partial_model([x], training=False)   # runs the model in test mode
```

Alternatively, if you insist on using `K.function` and want to toggle learning phase in eager mode, you can use `eager_learning_phase_scope` from `tensorflow.python.keras.backend` (note that this module is a superset of `tensorflow.keras.backend` and contains internal functions, such as the mentioned one, which may change in future versions):

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import eager_learning_phase_scope

fn = K.function([model.input], [model.layers[1].output])

# run in test mode, i.e. 0 means test
with eager_learning_phase_scope(value=0):
    output_test = fn([x])

# run in training mode, i.e. 1 means training
with eager_learning_phase_scope(value=1):
    output_train = fn([x])
```

Comment: Interesting approach, but I wonder of its efficiency and memory impact; every `Model` adds some tensors to the graph - with repeated use, aren't we polluting with non garbage-collected tensors? Or won't collection be intensive for large models? Btw, the use-case is with multiple outputs, for which your approach still holds.

Comment: Then again the approach I had in mind is [this](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/see-rnn/blob/1.14.6/see_rnn/inspect_gen.py#L234), which can double RAM use; worst-case I suppose `K.function` is still usable, but it does `Model` under the hood anyway. `eager_learning_phase_scope` was introduced in 2.3 I presume?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon No, it exists since 1.14. I am not certain about the impact of memory usage since my knowledge of very low-level TF is limited, especially about 2.x which it seems has had tons of low level optimization and changes in graph execution compared to 1.x which I am more familiar; therefore, I don't want to just speculate about that since it might be wrong or incomplete. However, there are tools you use for that purpose. One of them is TF Profiler and particularly its [Memory Profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#memory_profile_tool) which gives a per-op report.

Comment: Fair enough. Btw, may wish to bench your models in TF 2.3.0 Eager; I found in Colab it literally _doubled_ the speed of a large-model large-data setup (relative to 2.2-) ... and halved it for Graph execution. Unsure what's up with latter, but TF's either better utilizing CUDA with former or some new genius. No such differences on my GPU though, so it seems device-dependent.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Since the rollout of TF 2.0 and eager mode, there have been a lot of weird issues, inconsistent or surprising behavior. Sometimes, I don't know if I should be happy about the improvements and new features, or be mad about those frustrating issues. Thanks for the information, though.

Comment: Question badged. A correction, my results were due to GPU thermal paste vaporizing, and TF 2.3.0 seems to have beat all its previous versions. Regardless I've had it with TF and moved to Pytorch; hard for me to see TF undoing own mess, but best of luck to its users.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```