# ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`. Received: 0 (missing previous layer metadata). How do I resolve this issue?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

The below error is showing when I am trying to get features for leveraging SVM for classification. The full details is described below.

Model: "sequential"

---

## Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #

conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 32, 32, 64)        1792

---

activation (Activation)      (None, 32, 32, 64)        0

---

conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 32, 32, 64)        36928

---

activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 32, 32, 64)        0

---

max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 16, 16, 64)        0

---

dropout (Dropout)            (None, 16, 16, 64)        0

---

conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)       73856

---

activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 16, 16, 128)       0

---

conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 16, 128)       147584

---

activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 16, 16, 128)       0

---

max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 8, 8, 128)         0

---

dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 8, 8, 128)         0

---

conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 256)         295168

---

activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 8, 8, 256)         0

---

conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 256)         590080

---

activation_5 (Activation)    (None, 8, 8, 256)         0

---

conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 256)         590080

---

activation_6 (Activation)    (None, 8, 8, 256)         0

---

max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 4, 4, 256)         0

---

dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 4, 4, 256)         0

---

flatten (Flatten)            (None, 4096)              0

---

dense (Dense)                (None, 1024)              4195328

---

activation_7 (Activation)    (None, 1024)              0

---

dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0

---

dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              1049600

---

activation_8 (Activation)    (None, 1024)              0

---

dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0

---

dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                10250

---

## activation_9 (Activation)    (None, 10)                0

Total params: 6,990,666
Trainable params: 6,990,666
Non-trainable params: 0

## After that I check the Layers definitions

```
from keras import backend as K
for l in range(len(model.layers)):
    print(l, model.layers[l])
```

## I tried to get feature extraction layer

```
getFeature = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],
                        [model.layers[26].output])
```

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
1 # feature extraction layer
2 getFeature = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()],
----> 3                         [model.layers[26].output])

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in function(inputs, outputs, updates, name, **kwargs)
3934     from tensorflow.python.keras import models  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
3935     from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import tf_utils  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
-> 3936     model = models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
3937
3938     wrap_outputs = isinstance(outputs, list) and len(outputs) == 1

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in **new**(cls, *args, **kwargs)
240       # Functional model
241       from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
--> 242       return functional.Functional(*args, **kwargs)
243     else:
244       return super(Model, cls).**new**(cls, *args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
458     finally:
459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in **init**(self, inputs, outputs, name, trainable)
113     #     'arguments during initialization. Got an unexpected argument:')
114     super(Functional, self).**init**(name=name, trainable=trainable)
--> 115     self._init_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
116
117   @trackable.no_automatic_dependency_tracking

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
458     finally:
459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs)
142       base_layer_utils.create_keras_history(self._nested_outputs)
143
--> 144     self._validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs()
145
146     # A Network does not create weights of its own, thus it is already

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs(self)
637                          'must come from `tf.keras.Input`. '
638                          'Received: ' + str(x) +
--> 639                          ' (missing previous layer metadata).')
640       # Check that x is an input tensor.
641       # pylint: disable=protected-access

ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`. Received: 0 (missing previous layer metadata).

My tensorflow version is 2.3.0 and keras is 2.4.3 respectively.

Comment: Please include the full traceback in your question

Comment: Please have a look Dr. Snoopy. Thank you.

Comment: That is not the traceback. The traceback is the whole exception text that python outputs, it starts with "Traceback:".

Comment: Please have a look. Sorry to bother you Dr Snoopy.

Comment: Facing similar problem while using KNN for classification.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this issue?

Comment: The answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63238203/how-to-get-intermediate-outputs-in-tf-2-3-eager-with-learning-phase) by @today solved this for me.