# Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`. Received: 0 (missing previous layer metadata) and cant find the cause

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I got an error of ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`. Received: 0 (missing previous layer metadata) and i cant find the cause

this is my error trace and my code

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-8058f3a2fd50> in <module>()
      6   test_loss, test_accuracy = eg.test(dg.user_test)
      7   print('Test set: Loss=%.4f ; Accuracy=%.1f%%' % (test_loss, test_accuracy * 100))
----> 8   eg.save_embeddings('embeddings.csv')

7 frames
<ipython-input-5-54ff9897b1c3> in save_embeddings(self, file_name)
     66     inp = self.m.input                                           # input placeholder
     67     outputs = [layer.output for layer in self.m.layers]          # all layer outputs
---> 68     functor = K.function([inp, K.learning_phase()], outputs )   # evaluation function
     69 
     70     #append embeddings to vectors

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py in function(inputs, outputs, updates, name, **kwargs)
   3934     from tensorflow.python.keras import models  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
   3935     from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import tf_utils  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
-> 3936     model = models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
   3937 
   3938     wrap_outputs = isinstance(outputs, list) and len(outputs) == 1

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    240       # Functional model
    241       from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import functional  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
--> 242       return functional.Functional(*args, **kwargs)
    243     else:
    244       return super(Model, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in __init__(self, inputs, outputs, name, trainable)
    113     #     'arguments during initialization. Got an unexpected argument:')
    114     super(Functional, self).__init__(name=name, trainable=trainable)
--> 115     self._init_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
    116 
    117   @trackable.no_automatic_dependency_tracking

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs)
    142       base_layer_utils.create_keras_history(self._nested_outputs)
    143 
--> 144     self._validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs()
    145 
    146     # A Network does not create weights of its own, thus it is already

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _validate_graph_inputs_and_outputs(self)
    637                          'must come from `tf.keras.Input`. '
    638                          'Received: ' + str(x) +
--> 639                          ' (missing previous layer metadata).')
    640       # Check that x is an input tensor.
    641       # pylint: disable=protected-access

ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`. Received: 0 (missing previous layer metadata).
```

and this is my snipped code:

```
class EmbeddingsGenerator:
  def  __init__(self, train_users, data):
    self.train_users = train_users

    #preprocess
    self.data = data.sort_values(by=['timestamp'])
    #make them start at 0
    self.data['userId'] = self.data['userId'] - 1
    self.data['itemId'] = self.data['itemId'] - 1
    self.user_count = self.data['userId'].max() + 1
    self.movie_count = self.data['itemId'].max() + 1
    self.user_movies = {} #list of rated movies by each user
    for userId in range(self.user_count):
      self.user_movies[userId] = self.data[self.data.userId == userId]['itemId'].tolist()
    self.m = self.model()

  def model(self, hidden_layer_size=100):
    m = Sequential()
    m.add(Dense(hidden_layer_size, input_shape=(1, self.movie_count)))
    m.add(Dropout(0.2))
    m.add(Dense(self.movie_count, activation='softmax'))
    m.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return m
  
  def generate_input(self, user_id):
    '''
    Returns a context and a target for the user_id
    context: user's history with one random movie removed
    target: id of random removed movie
    '''
    user_movies_count = len(self.user_movies[user_id])
    #picking random movie
    random_index = np.random.randint(0, user_movies_count-1) # -1 avoids taking the last movie
    #setting target
    target = np.zeros((1, self.movie_count))
    target[0][self.user_movies[user_id][random_index]] = 1
    #setting context
    context = np.zeros((1, self.movie_count))
    context[0][self.user_movies[user_id][:random_index] + self.user_movies[user_id][random_index+1:]] = 1
    return context, target

  def train(self, nb_epochs = 300, batch_size = 10000):
    '''
    Trains the model from train_users's history
    '''
    for i in range(nb_epochs):
      print('%d/%d' % (i+1, nb_epochs))
      batch = [self.generate_input(user_id=np.random.choice(self.train_users) - 1) for _ in range(batch_size)]
      X_train = np.array([b[0] for b in batch])
      y_train = np.array([b[1] for b in batch])
      self.m.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=1, validation_split=0.5)

  def test(self, test_users, batch_size = 100000):
    '''
    Returns [loss, accuracy] on the test set
    '''
    batch_test = [self.generate_input(user_id=np.random.choice(test_users) - 1) for _ in range(batch_size)]
    X_test = np.array([b[0] for b in batch_test])
    y_test = np.array([b[1] for b in batch_test])
    return self.m.evaluate(X_test, y_test)

  def save_embeddings(self, file_name):
    '''
    Generates a csv file containg the vector embedding for each movie.
    '''
    inp = self.m.input                                           # input placeholder
    outputs = [layer.output for layer in self.m.layers]          # all layer outputs
    functor = K.function([inp, K.learning_phase()], outputs )   # evaluation function

    #append embeddings to vectors
    vectors = []
    for movie_id in range(self.movie_count):
      movie = np.zeros((1, 1, self.movie_count))
      movie[0][0][movie_id] = 1
      layer_outs = functor([movie])
      vector = [str(v) for v in layer_outs[0][0][0]]
      vector = '|'.join(vector)
      vectors.append([movie_id, vector])

    #saves as a csv file
    embeddings = pd.DataFrame(vectors, columns=['item_id', 'vectors']).astype({'item_id': 'int32'})
    embeddings.to_csv(file_name, sep=';', index=False)
    files.download(file_name)
```

this is the part of code which call the save_embeddings method

```
if True: # Generate embeddings?
  eg = EmbeddingsGenerator(dg.user_train, pd.read_csv('ml-100k/u.data', sep='\t', names=['userId', 'itemId', 'rating', 'timestamp']))
  eg.train(nb_epochs=300)
  train_loss, train_accuracy = eg.test(dg.user_train)
  print('Train set: Loss=%.4f ; Accuracy=%.1f%%' % (train_loss, train_accuracy * 100))
  test_loss, test_accuracy = eg.test(dg.user_test)
  print('Test set: Loss=%.4f ; Accuracy=%.1f%%' % (test_loss, test_accuracy * 100))
  eg.save_embeddings('embeddings.csv')
```

Comment: You can find the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63238203/